# Is there a \subsubsubsection command?

Tags: sectioning

I could do `\subsection{}` and `\subsubsection{}` but not `\subsubsubsection{}`. This command does not seem to be available in LaTeX. Is there an alternative command?

Comment: The sectioning command one level down the hierarchy from `\subsubsection` is called `\paragraph`.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`\subsubsubsection` doesn't exist but, instead, you can use `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`, which will generate something like 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.1.1. .

To include this in your table of contents, you have to declare `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` and `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}`. For subparagraph, use `{5}`.

There are 7 levels of sections (depending on the document)

- -1     `\part{part}`
- 0     `\chapter{chapter}`
- 1     `\section{section}`
- 2     `\subsection{subsection}`
- 3     `\subsubsection{subsubsection}`
- 4     `\paragraph{paragraph}`
- 5     `\subparagraph{subparagraph}`

`\part` and `\chapter` are only available in `report` and `book`.

Comment: I used \paragraph  but the title came out without any numbers!. I do not like it not numbered.

Comment: when I included \setcounter{tocdpth}{4} and \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} my file failed to compile!!.

Comment: This answer does not work for me. No numbers are displayed and the text in the brackets is not displayed as a headline. Which document type did you use?

Comment: I have to disagree with the other comments. This works perfect. I get the title, the numbering and the additional level in the toc.

Comment: Using `\paragraph{}` does not add any numbering, and as @user1511417 said, it is not displayed as a header. Contrary to what the answer says, you have to include `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` if you want the numbering and `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` to have it appear in the table of contents. However, the paragraph title is still inlined and does not appear as a proper header. On top of that, `\paragraph{}` adds a dot to the end of the paragraph title, which might be unwanted.