# \setcounter{} destroyed my file, it does not compile any more

Tags: counters

I was doing `\paragraph` to include a third subsection but my third subsection came out not numbered at all. I got help from someone suggesting me to use `setcounter` (see my related question: [Is there a \subsubsubsection command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186981/is-there-a-subsubsubsection-command/186982#186982) ). The problem is that my thesis failed to compile! I deleted the command, and my file still not working! I used:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

what could be happening??

Comment: I highly doubt that `\setcounter{}` has eaten, smashed, blown up, or otherwise d[e]stroyed your thesis. Try deleting the `*.aux` file and see if the problem is resolved. If not, post a minimal example and someone will surely be able to help.

Comment: Analyze your error message (location, ...). Probably one or more of your `\paragraph` titles contain fragile stuff that breaks during the move to the table of contents. Use `\protect` to protect fragile commands in `\paragraph`.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still learning latex but at the same time I have a deadline so I had better not fell in so many errors.

Comment: oh, I finally figured it out. When I deleted the setcounter commands I used in my main thesis file, I did leave a space (an empty line) which was causing the problem. Now , I deleted the line and everything is working fine except that I am still not able to do subsubsubsection{} using \paragraph; \paragraph did not do any numbers , it showed a title but without any numbers.

Comment: \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}}}%
   {\end{list}}  (I inserted the setcounter commands right in the middle between \setlength and \end{list} and when I deleted the commands, I left an empty line which caused the compilation problem).

Comment: Have you looked at the accepted answer to the question your original question was closed as a duplicate of? [That answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60212/21344) seems to do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Please change your question title. Nothing 'destroyed [your] file'. That suggests that you `tex` file disappeared into the ether which is not the case.

Comment: cfr, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sections are numbered up to `secnumdepth` which is 3 in article and `\paragraph` is level 4 heading so to have numbered paragraphs use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}`

Comment: I did it but I had the following error:\begin{document} ended by \end{list}

Comment: here I inserted it just before ending the list {\begin{list}{}%
  {\renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\hfill\textnormal{##1 =}}%
   \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\textnormal{#1 =}}%
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
   \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
   \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}}}%
   \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
   {\end{list}}

Comment: @Naema It makes no sense to change the settings there, they should be in the document preamble

Comment: @Naema you need to post the error but also _every_ question should have a _complete_ small document that generates the error. Start from a copy of the document and delete everything you can delete while still having the error, your example code in teh question should have _everything_ from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: IT worked but gave me 2.1.2.0.1  (I should not have the zero in there), how to remove it?. I used /setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} and used \paragraph

Comment: @Naema that means you have skipped one level \section,\subsection,\subsubsection,\paragraph. But you _still_ have not provided an example in your question that demonstrates any problem, so impossible to guess.

Comment: David, yes , you are right. I figured out today that the level subsubsection is missed. The problem is solved now.

Comment: OK next time _please_ put a proper example in the question:-)

Comment: sure David. I wanted to include this third subsection in my table of contents but could not know how. Should I use a different command?

Comment: @Naema sorry I have no idea what you mean by that, but don't ask new questions in comments, if you have a new question ask a new question _with a complete example document that shows the problem_.

Comment: @Naema unless you mean `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}`

Comment: I put those commands \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
 but not sure if I put them in the right place. I have a different file for each chapter of my thesis and I have a main file in which I did the settings.