# \subsubsubsection for scrbook

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

Why does \subsubsubsection not work for \documentclass{scrbook} and how can I force it anyway?

There is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsubsubsection{Subsubsubsection}
\end{document}
```

With this MWE a get an error: "undefined control sequence \subsubsubsection" and the pdf looks like this:

[image]

But I need "1.1.1.1.1. Subsubsubsection" in the last line.

Comment: `\paragraph` is the next level after `\subsubsection`. Set the `secnumdepth` to 4, if you want it numbered as well.

Comment: I have the same problem and I use \paragraph{} or \subsubsection*{}.

Comment: See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186981/is-there-a-subsubsubsection-command), and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295115/section-depth-5-subsubsubsection-doesnt-work)..

Comment: @Troy The questions aims at KOMA-script. The solutions you are refering to seem to require a standard documentclass. Years ago I used the alnumsec package for the additional level, but maybe KOMA-script supports additional levels out of the box now.

Comment: @KeksDose True. It's not an exact duplicate, but I figured since the solution was the same..

Comment: How can you mark a question as a duplicate, when answers here and there have completely different solutions?

Comment: @KeksDose Just because the solutions are different does not mean that they are wrong. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186982/36296 works perfectly well for the MWE of this question.

Comment: @samcarter That's not the issue. The questions are different, the older questions use standard classes, this one a KOMA-script class. The answers here are not a hack into the internals of LaTeX, but use a well documented feature of KOMA-script.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update** (needs KOMA-Script version 3.26b)

The original answer below is still correct. But there are the new command `\RedeclareSectionCommands`, the new options `runin` and `afterindent`. And there are some options predefined for new section levels using `style=section`.

Suggestion 1: Declaring new section level `subsubsubsection` as a displayed title

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  counterwithin=subsubsection,
  afterskip=1.5ex plus .2ex,
  beforeskip=3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
  afterindent=false,
  level=\paragraphnumdepth,
  tocindent=10em,
  tocnumwidth=5em
]{subsubsubsection}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsubsectionnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subparagraphtocdepth}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  level=\numexpr\subsubsubsectionnumdepth+1\relax,
  toclevel=\numexpr\subsubsubsectiontocdepth+1\relax,
  increaselevel
]{paragraph,subparagraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  counterwithin=subsubsubsection,
  tocindent=12em,
  tocnumwidth=6em
]{paragraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=14em,
  tocnumwidth=7em
]{subparagraph}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsubsubsection{Subsubsubsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Suggestion 2: Redefining `paragraph` as a displayed title:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterskip=1.5ex plus .2ex,
  afterindent=false
]{paragraph}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\paragraphnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\paragraphtocdepth}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer**

You can declare a new section level `subsubsubsection`. But then you have to redeclare `paragraph` and `subparagraph` to adjust the its levels etc.:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  counterwithin=subsubsection,
  font=\normalsize,
  afterskip=1.5ex plus .2ex,
  beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
  indent=0pt,
  level=4,
  tocstyle=section,
  toclevel=4,
  tocindent=10em,
  tocnumwidth=5em
]{subsubsubsection}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsubsectionnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsubsectiontocdepth}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  level=5,
  counterwithin=subsubsubsection,
  toclevel=5,
  tocindent=12em,
  tocnumwidth=6em
]{paragraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  level=6,
  toclevel=6,
  tocindent=14em,
  tocnumwidth=7em
]{subparagraph}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsubsubsection{Subsubsubsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If do not use `\paragraph` as a runin title, you can redeclare section level `paragraph` using a positive value for `afterskip`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterskip=1.5ex plus .2ex,
  beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex
]{paragraph}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\paragraphnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\paragraphtocdepth}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use `\paragraph` and to redefine its formatting:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    counterwithin=subsubsection,
    toclinefill=\hfill,
    tocindent=3.5ex,
    tocnumwidth=1ex,
    tocdynnumwidth=true, 
    tocraggedentrytext=true,
    tocentryformat=\fontintoc\itshape,
    tocpagenumberformat=\fontintoc,
    beforeskip=10pt,%
    afterskip=1pt,
    font=\normalfont\itshape
    ]{paragraph}



    \begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Subsubsubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you want to leave `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` as is, then you need only new level numbers for it and can then define `\subsubsubsection`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[level=6,toclevel=6]{subparagraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[level=5,toclevel=5]{paragraph}    
\DeclareSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  counterwithin=subsubsection,
  font=\normalsize,
  afterskip=1ex plus .2ex,
  beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex,
  indent=0pt,
  level=4,
  tocstyle=section,
  toclevel=4,
  tocindent=10em,
  tocnumwidth=5em
]{subsubsubsection}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsubsectionnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsubsectiontocdepth}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Chapter}
    \section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
    \subsubsubsection{Subsubsubsection}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\paragraph{foo} \lipsum[1]
\subparagraph{bar} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```