# how to make \paragraph or \subparagraph show up in pdf side panel but w/o #'s in text

Tags: sectioning, pdftex, numbering, bookmarks

I was reading this question:

[Is there a \subsubsubsection command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186981/is-there-a-subsubsubsection-command?noredirect=1)

and I really like, for navigational purposes, seeing the outline in my side-panel (xreader, etc.), but I don't want to see something like 3.2.3.1 in the paper.

I tried using `\paragraph*{}`, `\subparagraph*{}`, etc, but I couldn't get it to show up in the side panel without showing up in the paper.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't want to have the numbers in text, but the paragraphs etc. should appear in the bookmark any way?

Comment: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` and `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}` should work. The paragraphs etc. are not numbered in text, but still appear in the `bookmarks` (and ToC, however!)

Comment: Nice! Thanks, yes, it worked. I'll accept if you want it as an answer...

Comment: Actually, it is somehow related to my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291312/31729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tocdepth` counter value determines which structure level will appear in the `ToC` and in the related bookmark panel. Displaying all usual structure levels (i.e. from `\part` to `\subparagraph`), say `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}`.

In order to hide the section etc. numbers use an appropriate value for the `secnumdepth` counter. Hiding paragraphs etc. needs a value of `3` only.

More options are available if the `bookmark` package is loaded.

Don't forget to compile twice to make changes effective.

For a more detailed description see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291312 please.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=5]{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}% Only down to \subsubsection shall be numbered
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo chapter}
\section{Foo section}
\subsection{Foo subsection}

\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}

\paragraph{Foo paragraph}

\subparagraph{Foo subparagraph}

\end{document}
```